# PhoneGap InAppBrowser how to disable eror page on network non available

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I am implementing a phonegap app that will get app news in form of the inappBrowser functionality. The problem is that when The users network is disconnected the url that will open is the one that says "Unable to connect to the Internet and cannot reach server at http://xxxxx.com" this makes the user see that he is using a browser not an app per say. so I want to customise this browser page that load when network is not available

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
     var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
     ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
     ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
     ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert('error: ' + event.message); });
     ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { alert(event.type); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the network plugin and test to see if you have a connection.

[API documentation](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.network-information)

You probably also need to handle the offline event so you know when you lose your connection.

```
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

function onOffline() {
    // Handle the offline event
}
```

**Solution 2**
You could use the loadError event on the inappbrowser and do something when it fails to load

Comment: perfect, that great. But I think I need to rephrase my question, if the page is a 404 page, how do i use .htaccess on phonegap. LOL. incase of 404 page or invalid url, the default is always "web page not found";  how do we customise it

Comment: Are you sure there isn't still a cell network? It has to go to NONE not just cell.  There used to be an onChange event

Comment: If there is no change event then you can always just check it yourself before going to the site.

Comment: In answer to your first comment the InAppBrowser is a browser not a server so you can't use .htaccess. What is displayed when there is no connection is up to the implementation of the webview. So you would have to go into each platform and change the implementation of the inAppbrowser. So I would suggest using either of the methods I proposed